# how to get control of sub window using autohot key?

Tags: autohotkey

I am able to get controllist of main window using :-

```
 SetTimer, WatchActiveWindow, 200
 return
 WatchActiveWindow:
 WinGet, ControlList, ControlList, A
ToolTip, %ControlList%
 return
```

But unable to get controllist of many app which have sub window like vlc ,"open Media" window did not show any control etc.
Plz help

Comment: Start `winget` on a new line, otherwise Autohotkey executes only ONE command.

Comment: But it still did not list control for sub window

Comment: Right click on any ahk icon in the tray and select "Window Spy". Then you can point to any window to see the controls.

Comment: It only show controls for main window only; its show title name for sub window not its control

Comment: Unfortunately, it means that there are no controls that you can directly manipulate, so you'll have to send mouse clicks using relative positions.

Comment: Look at this ;it may solve my problem but its dropbox link are not working. Address is.       :-                                 https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/17400-how-to-get-control-names-and-contents/

Comment: Why not use "window spy"? ... or try `F5::keyhistory` to press a key F5

Comment: Try AutoHotkey's AccViewer, it can finds all sorts of subelements within windows/controls.
You should then be able to do actions involving those subelements via the Acc.ahk function library.
Things like text retrieval, or triggering a button.